# document.querySelectorAll('object') -- regression on chrome v47+

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I have a javascript regression in my code since a chrome update...

I use SVG `<object type="image/svg+xml">` in my markup.

I use to iterate over them with a simple `document.querySelectorAll('object')` which used to return an array-like of elements.

--

Now with chrome v47+, it returns a list of weird `function`:

[image]

Does anyone aware of this and maybe know a workaround ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the Chromium issue tracker for confirmation that this is a regression? (Also, if it's not there and you're certain, you should open a new issue.)

Comment: You could try converting it to an array iterable with `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("object"))`

Comment: Does this only happen with `<object>` elements? I tried `document.querySelectorAll("div")` and it returned an ordinary `NodeList`.

Comment: @Barmar : yes only for `<object>` elements (for what I now know)

Comment: This is very interesting. Can you please post a [complete, minimal and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) somewhere (jsbin, liveweave, etc)?

Comment: @Zirak : sure, here it is http://s.codepen.io/abernier/debug/KVpNjx -- just iterate over `<object>`s and `console.log` each

Comment: @abernier, I can confirm it on osx version too, but I'm not sure you need a workaround, except if you do check for `typeof document.querySelectorAll("object")` : the function returned seems to have all properties a normal `HTMLObjectElement` should have. Also, this is not related to the `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` methods, `getElementById()` and even `document.createElement('object')` will just return the same function instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known regression. There are issues reported in Chromium Issue Tracker.

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=554001
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543932

The above issues show that in v47 you get the 'rawScopes' error as you found. But it in v48 you don't get an that error but get a *function anonymous()* returned in the console. While a lot of DOM operations [could still work](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=554001#c5), it's unclear whether this behaviour will be reverted anytime soon.

For now, the change has been merged in and the issues have been closed with this comment
from a [Chromium Developer](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543932#c31) directed at other Chromium developers:

> If you think there's any ambiguity or that people might disagree with the change, always good to send a heads up to blink-dev to gather people's opinions

---

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34318437/3649209