# Finding selenium object tag using java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I previously had my code working no problems and was able to find an object tagin a web page using selenium with no problem. I'm using a chrome driver to access the page as I noticed that the DOM showed nothing inside it when I used IE and I need to reach the contents of the object tag. That said, the code I used was as follows:

```
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement object = browser.findElement(By.tagName("object"));
browser.switchTo().frame(object);
```

At the moment, I'm having a problem though where I get an error from the second line that reads:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

The object tag I'm looking at is (mostly, due to removing business related sections) as follows:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="classified" width="1600px" height="900px">...</object>
```

Any idea of what might be wrong or if there's a better way to do this in java?

Comment: A couple side notes: I have looked into this for about 2 days without finding much of anything and there is only 1 object tag on the page.

Answer (score 2):

There were the issues reported at Chromium project:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543932
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=554001

We had such issue in the internal automation project but we also had an option to query `div` instead of `object` (the way how we fixed it).

I changed the tests back to querying `object` element and I got the same exception:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.18.343837 (52eb4041461e46a6b73308ebb19e85787ced4281) on port 18276
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {}
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
System info: host: 'xxx-MacBook-Pro-4.local', ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.xx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByTagName(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByTagName.findElement(By.java:331)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
    ... 9 more
```

Browser: `Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)`
*(latest stable version for today [OS X platform])*

Comment: I didn't really follow what was talked about in the first link, but the second mentions chrome ver. 47 being an issue but not 46 or 48 so I'm wondering if that might be related since the version of chrome loaded by the chrome driver is 47. I'll have to look into this

Comment: Do you know how to change the version of Google Chrome for chrome driver (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)?

Comment: Answer is updated. There are a lot of the ways to change version of Google Chrome: you can create new user on OS level and install specific version of Google Chrome or you can set the path to Google Chrome in selenium. Feel free to ask new question if you were not find an answer on SO =P

Answer (score 1):

I think it is synchronous problem.

I will suggest you to use [WebDriver Wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Here is code that you can try:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tag("object")));
```

Comment: I was hoping that was it but I get the error of: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {}. I think it finds it, but for some reason thinks that it is not a web element.

Comment: What you are trying to perform after switchTo().frame(object); ? What is Object is in this <Object> </object> it is video or pdf file ?

Comment: It's a svg-xml or an image inside of the object and I need to get some text fields that are within some of the tags. I can't go directly to them without the switchTo because the object acts like an <iFrame>

Comment: Can you add that entire project ? If you can

Comment: Considering this is for work, I cannot provide the whole projects. I can offer more snippets, but the only thing not mentioned is how i connect to the web page and reach the one I need as well as specifics of what I do after i switch to the object tag. Which of those would you like more information/code snippets for?

Comment: I think here is final solution, You need to take value in string. Here is way   String EntireObjectValue = browser.findElement(By.tagName("object")).toString();                                                  You will have all value in string and check string have that exact text you want. Here is assertions  : assertTrue(EntireObjectValue.contains("EXPECTED TEXT"). It will fail always if do not find content. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however due to the object tag not being converted to a WebElement, this won't work.